# Matching double symbol

Tags: regex

Hey guys I've been working with this one for a little while.  I can't seem to get it.

Here is what I have so far

```
(@[^{2,}+)([^(\s\W\d{2}]+)(\b)
```

http://rubular.com/r/zlx3j00Wjl

Although this is not excepting periods in the match.

I basically need to match this.

> @**function.name**(param)

I just need to match **function.name**.  This does that.

http://rubular.com/r/hWMB72LsWT

I don't want to match this

> @@function.name(param)
>   hello@@test.com`

Didn't know if anyone has any ideas.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go at it ([here it is on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/A4FEslj7lU)):

```
(?<!@)@(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\([^)]*\)
```

Explained:

```
(?<!@)@         # an '@' not preceded by an '@'
(\w+(?:\.\w+)*) # any number of xxx.xxx.xxx, captured into a group
\([^)]*\)       # brackets, containing anything that isn't a closing bracket
```

Since this is Ruby, you might not care about matching parentheses. In that case you can just remove the last section.

Comment: Thanks man this was the final pattern that got me there.  I modified it to this  (?<![\w,@])@(\w+(?:\.\w+)*) to prevent highlighting(this is for textmate) if a character comes before.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookahead: `@(?!@)` matches a `@` not followed by another `@`.

Comment: You actually want negative lookbehind, since you want to match things after the `@`: `(?<!@)@...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:^|\s)@+([^(]+)
```

You will have `function.match` and `function.name` in the first group, will not match `hello@@test.com`. Rubular:

- http://rubular.com/r/b8gy1LcVGz

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(?!.*@@)^@([^()\s]+)\b
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/6EdT746exs)

- I removed some brackets from your expression
- I removed the Quantifier from the leading `@`
- `(?!.*@@)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will fail if it finds anywhere in the string two `@` characters in a row.

I am not sure about your requirements, if there is all the time a set of brackets at the end, then you don't need your word boundary. If there can be similar strings without brackets that you don't want to match, then I would add another lookahead to ensure this assertion:

```
?!.*@@)^@([^()\s]+)(?=\()
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/7MKTvoEvb5)